# A Oracle Recursive query,it is so slow,why?

Tags: sql, oracle

**I want to query the data table of the specified level.**

For example, I would like to inquire about the depth of the relationship between the father and son 1,Then it's my way.

**1. I first recursively query the level of all data。**

```
SELECT c.cid,pcid,level lv 
  FROM qm_product_cat c 
  start with pcid='0' CONNECT BY PRIOR CID=pcid
```

**2. And then i query this,**

```
 select * from (
 SELECT c.cid,pcid,level lv 
  FROM qm_product_cat c 
  start with pcid='0' CONNECT BY PRIOR CID=pcid
  ) where lv = 1
```

**Questions**: It is so slow and a lot of repetition. Why? Do you have a better way?

Comment: What is the query plan and the number of rows in the product table? Have you considered an index on the cid and pcid tables - I assume cid is a primary key so already has an index but pcid might not?

Comment: if you only want to get one level back then you don't need to do a connect by, just join the table once to itself.

Comment: Please show sample data in a table, and expected output, and explain plans, etc.

Comment: Oracle's optimizer cannot infer that you want to stop at level 1, you must include level <= 1 in the connect by: CONNECT BY PRIOR CID=pcid AND level <= 1; (if you want to get level X include level <= X in the connect by)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are interested only in rows from first level then you don't need hierarchical query at all, nor inner join query, 
simply add `where pcid='0'` clause:

```
select cid, pcid from qm_product_cat where pcid = '0';
```

...but if you insist on hierarchy, or if you wanted rows from level up to three you could add condition for level in `connect by clause`:

```
select cid,pcid,level lv 
  from qm_product_cat c 
  start with pcid='0' 
  connect by prior cid=pcid AND LEVEL<=1;
```

This way query stops at specified level and does not go down further.

<sup>[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/53e32/2)</sup>